# How to get updated value of textbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get the new value of the textbox but I always get the old one. Please help

I have a input type text with a value generated on PHP.

```
$description = "Pink Tie";
<input type="text" id="txtDesc" value="<?php echo $description ?>" />
<button type="submit" onclick="updateDesc();">Update</button>
```

Output: "Pink Tie"

Let say I changed it to "Blue Tie", then get the new description on jQuery

On JS:

```
function updateDesc(){
  var desc = $( "#txtDesc" ).val();
  alert(desc);
}
```

Output: "Pink Tie"

I get the same output. How will I get the new input?

Comment: Change to "Blue tile" where in your php file? I hope so that's not the case, is it?

Comment: Why are you using `type` twice `type="button" type="submit"`?

Comment: Are you using ajax or regualr form submit? `onclick="updateDesc(); retun false;"` is going to make your funtion work but stop the submition

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Satpal, It was just a typographical error on my post. But my code was not actually like that. Thanks!

Comment: @kidwon, change the Blue Tie by typing a new input into the textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used jQuery and it works.

On HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="PinkTie" id="txtDesc"/>
<button id="button" onclick="updateDesc();">Update</button>
```

On Javascript:

```
function updateDesc(){
       var desc = $( "#txtDesc" ).val();
       alert(desc);
}
```

Note that javascript function must be put before html.
This is demo: http://code.freetuts.net/editor.html?id=239

Answer (score 1):

```
A simple solution for this problem is use keyup function .This function show current value of textbox.
->html 
<input type="text" value="PinkTie" id="txtDesc"/>
<button id="button">Update</button>
->JavaScript
$("#txtDesc").keyup(function(){
var desc = $( "#txtDesc" ).val();
       alert(desc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('keyup','#txtDesc',updateDesc);
```

`keyup` - after press the key
`keydown` - when press the key